# How to insert overwrite partitioned table in BigQuery UI?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, bigdata

We can insert data into specific partition of partitioned table, here we need to specify  partition value.But my requirement is to overwrite all partitions in a table in one query using UI. Can we perform this operation?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you ever need to do this?

Comment: @GrahamPolley as pub/sub only has a 7 day message retention and we're currently developing, I would like to overwrite partition data for dates that have since updated (youtube transfer file success dates we can see in the BigQuery UI). I could just recreate the entire table but as there are a few TBs of data, it would cost us some dollars. Thanks for the Dataflow tip below.

Answer (score 2):

Consulted bigquery team member. You can NOT write to all partitions in one query.

You can only write to a partition at a time.

Answer (score 2):

As [YY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9221183/y-y) has pointed out, you would not be able to do this directly in BigQuery/SQL with one query (you could script something to run N queries). However, if you spun up a Cloud Dataflow pipeline and configured it to have multiple `BigQueryIO` sinks, with each one (sink) overwriting a partition, this could be one way I can think of doing it in one shot. It would be a straightforward pipeline to spin up and run.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, BigQuery allows updating upto 2000 partitions in a single statement. If you need to just insert data into a partitioned table, you can use the INSERT DML statement to write to upto 2000 partitions in one statement. If you are updating or deleting existing partitions you can use the UPDATE or DELETE statements respectively. If you are both updating and inserting new data, you can use the MERGE DML statements to achieve this.